# Why my cronjob was launched on the bad day?

Tags: cron

I wanted to launch a job at the beggining of every month, but only on week days.

To do so, I've added this line in /etc/crontab file:

```
7 0 3-5 * 1-5  root  ( test "`date '+\%d'`" = "03" || test "`date '+\%u'`" = "1" ) && /path/to/my/script.sh
```

What was expected: script.sh launched on the 1st weekday between the 3rd and the 5th of the month (the "test" part is only there to be sure that it is launched once).

It works very well and this month, on the 3rd, the cronjob was run.

But, unfortunately, for an unknown reason, it was also launched today, the 8th of june, on monday.
I can understand that the "test" part works (`test "date '+%u'" = "1"` is true, and it is logical), but the "cron" part shouldn't be true (`7 0 3-5 * 1-5` is not true, we are the 8th).

So I was wondering, did I do something wrong, or is there is a deeper problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This, admittedly surprising, behavior is documented in `man 5 crontab` (emphasis mine):

> Commands are executed by cron(8) when the minute, hour, and month
>   of year fields match the current time, **and when *at least one* of
>   the two day fields (day of month, or day of week) match the    current
>   time** (see ``Note'' below).
>
> [...]
>
> Note: The day of a command's execution can be specified by two
>   fields — day of month,  and  day    of  week.   If both fields are
>   restricted (i.e., aren't *), **the command will be run when either
>
>   field matches the current time**.  For example,    ``30 4 1,15 * 5''
>   would cause a command to be run at 4:30 am on the 1st and 15th of each
>   month,    plus every Friday.

So, what you need to do is make your command test the time. Just like you do for making it run only once. Since this is getting kind of complicated, I would recommend having the check done in your script itself and then launching the cron command every day of the relevant month. Something like

```bash
## Check if this is a weekday 
[ $(date '+%u') -le 5 ] && [ $(date '+%u') -ge 1 ] || exit;
## Make sure it only runs once. If yesterday was also a weekday and 
## date >=3 and <=5, we can assume the script ran then and should exit. 
[ $(date -d yesterday '+%u') -le 5 ] && [ $(date -d yesterday '+%u') -ge 1 ] && 
 [ $(date -d yesterday '+%d') -le 3 ] && [ $(date -d yesterday '+%d') -ge 5  ] && exit;
## Rest of your script goes here
[...]
```

Then, from `cron`, launch your script only on days 3-5 of every month:

```
7 0 3-5 * *  /path/to/my/script.sh
```

Comment: Thanks! I admit that I didn't fully read the man page (well, in fact, I even read the man crontab -> man 1 crontab).
As you suggested, I only restrict on the day of month in the crontab file, and then I did this test in the script:
`[ $(date '+%u') -le 5 ] && ( [ "$(date '+%u')" = "1" ] || [ "$(date '+%d')" = "03" ] ) || exit;`

Comment: well done +1 @terdon, as per usual...